# For which dimensions do Neural Networks become favorable to multidimensional interpolation methods?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, gaussian-process, splines, interpolation

Say I have a high-dimensional function and I'm trying to approximate/interpolate it. The typical methods I've found were Gaussian Process, spline interpolation (and others here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Regular_grid), and neural networks.

I was searching the literature but I couldn't find papers that compare these methods in high dimensions ($D > 5)$. Have there been studies on this or resources for learning about the performance of each of these methods in high dimensions?

Comment: This is a difficult problem. Accordingly, only little can be said in general. If you are serious about this be prepared to dig deep and address at least: What function(s) do you want to approximate and what is the design of your problem (i.e. the observations you would like to interpolate/approximate). If you are not serious about it (i.e. pragmatic) just try a few models. There is plenty available out of the box.

Comment: Since you speak of interpolation, I am assuming you are in a noiseless situation. In such cases, the flexibility of the algorithm is the biggest factor, and not its theoretical properties like rates-of-convergence in noisy settings. Neural networks are natural for this as they are very flexible and are not-to-difficult to train. You might still want to use cross-validation since it is still possible to overfit. The Highly adaptive lasso (R package hal9001) is an easy out-of-the-box method that will also work well, and it performs internal cross-validation.

Comment: Regarding the highly adaptive lasso (hal9001 github ref=devel), if you set the tuning parameter $\lambda \approx 0$ and turn off cross-validation selection, it will actually perform exact linear interpolation. Make sure the following parameters are entered: "smoothness_orders = 1", "num_knots = c(500,500) [larger number means more knots and thus more exact interpolation. A smaller number will be more computationally efficient and give a smoother fit]". This actually just performs interpolation with the multivariate truncated power basis.

Comment: @gg The functions are complicated integrals so I'm aiming for a general algorithm that works for any nice function you throw at it. I can generate exact data, so the question is which methods have been shown to be reliable for high dimensions, if any.

Comment: @Abe,what does "reliable" even mean to you? Worst case? Average case? Some specific norm??? I fear you need to be much more specific to expect meaningful answers. There is just no single method which is "shown to be reliable for high dimensions". This is exactly why it is a difficult problem.

Comment: @gg to be more specific, 'reliable' as in low mean absolute error. I understand it might be difficult to make sweeping statements, which is why I was wondering if there have been papers addressing this very question. Thanks.